How to minimize $\| A x - b \|_1$
How can I minimize $\|A x - b\|_1$ where $A$ is not invertible?  Here, $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$.
I know that I can use the sub-gradient method, but that would be very slow.
I also know that I can use the primal-dual hybrid gradient method, which solves problems of the form $f(x) + g(Ax)$ where $f$ and $g$ are closed-convex proper.  PDHG is efficient when $f$ and $g$ have simple proximal operators.  However, this seems like overkill since $f=0$ for this problem.
Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Doesn't x=0 always minimize your function?

Yes, I wrote the question wrong.  I have now fixed it.  Thank you @lisyarus.

Even though $f$ is $0$, I don’t think PDHG (aka Chambolle-Pock) is overkill. Other possible approaches are using ADMM / Douglas-Rachford or reformulating the problem as a linear programming (LP) problem and using an LP solver.

Might be of interest: https://disp.ee.ntu.edu.tw/class/Algorithms-for-L1-Minimization.pdf

As an omen, whenever the entries of the matrices appearing in the problem can be stored, and we are dealing with max or  $\ell_1$ norm, always apply linear programming techniques. No faster method likely exists.  Notice that this problem is equivalent to $$\begin{array}{c c}
\text{minimize } & \sum^{m}_{i=1}  z_i \\
\text{subject to } & A x - b \leq z, \ - A x + b \leq z.
\end{array}$$ This problem can be efficiently solved by any standard linear programming technique.

What would a standard technique be?  Simplex method?

It depends on the problem. For small problems, the Simplex method is usually the fastest. When the problem becomes large, interior points methods become better. Usually, it is necessary to compare both to guarantee which one is better. In any case, you can safely Gurobi Optimizer, which is usually the fastest solver.

A last question.  My problems are usually matrix-free implementations of A where x has about 1,000,000 variables.  I think it's much too large for iterior point methods.  Would you still recommend the Gurobi Optimizer?

Your issue is your problem is matrix-free. You can try to store the matrix. It depends not on the matrix column size (variable number) but on whether it can be stored in your RAM. Usually, 32 GB or, in the worst case, 64 GB would suffice for such a small size.

Losing structure is the worst part of my suggestion. The only time I used Gurobi was when I had the matrix stored. Is Gurobi also matrix-free? I am not sure. Considering the number of applications matrix-free problems have, I would suppose it is, but I am unsure. Sorry for not knowing that.

don’t be silly!  Your answers have been excellent and I very much appreciate your thoughts.  Thank you.

I was seeing some discussions online and half a milion full matrix costs around 74 Gb of RAM. That's a lot. On the o hand, if the matrix is half sparse, maybe 64 Gb will be enough for your application. See here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/ram-needed-to-initialise-large-matrices/78302. I was thinking about a matrix with 1 milion entries, but that's far from your case. You need to see if you can store a matrix with sparse structure or something in order to 64 gb to be enough. I suppose you can use a sparse structure on your case and yet use Gurobi Optimizer.
